# How to retrieve category Id using url in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to retrieve the `category Id` using only the Category `URL` that I already have with me.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you need to get url_key from url & collection filter by url_key attrbiute

Comment: I'm new to magento 2. i want clear explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called `test.php` in the root of Magento 2 instance.

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
    $bootstrap->run($app);
```

Then create a file called `TestApp.php` in the same place with this content.

```
<?php
    class TestApp
        extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
        implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {
        public function launch()
        {
            $categoryFactory = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
            $categories = $categoryFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key','devops')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id']);

            echo $categories->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();
            return $this->_response;
        }

        public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Now just call test.php in the browser and everything that is placed in TestApp::launch() will be executed.

---

Comment: What do you mean by script file ?

Comment: My file in magento2 folder....(Not in module)

Comment: Okay. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: what is meant url_key,devops?

Comment: Replace devops with your category url key value. It is just for example.

Comment: One error was found in that................Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\App\Http::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Event\Manager, none given, called in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67574/discussion-between-kishan-patadia-and-mahalakshmi-m).